# Parameterized tests counter in Junit

Tags: java, testing, junit, count, parameterized

There is this situation: I have some parameterized tests which are ran from main class with result report afterwards. When something is parameterized it is printed to log and after tests are done failed results are displayed, for example:

```
Starting ChromeDriver (v2.10.267521) on port 24466
Only local connections are allowed.
HPPv1ACHTest - Parameterized ACH is :33
Test_32456[0](some.package): expected:<[A]00> but was:<[0]00>
```

so this 33 parameter was last test and I know it came out ok, however I want to know IDs of other tests same way Junit counts its report number in brackets "[]"(Test_32456[0]).
I wonder how it is possible to keep count of which parameterized test is running and put it into variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully undestand your question, but maybe the `name` parameter of the `Parameters` annotation solves your problem. You can use it to change the `[0]` part of the test's name. Please read the documentation of the [Parameterized runner](http://junit.org/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html).